# C# - How to create a non-detectable infinite loop?

Tags: c#, loops, infinite-loop

This is just an "I am Curious" question.

In C#-in-depth Jon Skeet says about lambda expressions:
*"if there is a nonvoid return type every code path has to return a compatible value."* (Page 233)

The footnote then says:
*"Code paths throwing exceptions don't need to return a value, of course, and neither do detectable infinite loops."* (Page 233)

I am wondering what constitutes a non-detectable infinite loop?

Can this be done by only logic? or it is done by using external factors like a database or file system?

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe he can clarify.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What Jon is referring to is described in section 8.1 of the specification. The compiler can detect only very simple infinite loops, like:

```
while(true) { if (0 != 0) return 123; }
```

The compiler is smart enough to see that the return is never reached, and therefore that the loop runs forever. It is legal, though crazy, to say:

```
int M() { while(true) { } }
```

because though there is no path which returns an int, there is also no path which returns *without* returning an int!

The compiler is not smart enough to find other kinds of infinite loops. For example:

```
int x = 123;
while(true) { if (x * 0 != 0) break; }
```

This is clearly an infinite loop. But the compiler doesn't know that. The compiler says "well, maybe there is some value of x where x * 0 is not zero, so then the break is reachable, so this isn't an infinite loop". You and I know that this is impossible because we know math, but the compiler does not.

Read section 8.1 if you want the details.

Comment: I don't actually remember writing this - which suggests that the footnote is due to your influence :)

Comment: @Jon: You originally wrote "Code paths throwing exceptions don't need to return a value, of course". I noted that detectable infinite loops also count as unreachable end points.

Comment: Right - that seems a more likely level of detail for each of us to come up with :)

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty trivial to create an infinite loop using external sources, or even abusing tools like interfaces.

For example:

```
  public interface INumbers
    {
        int GetNumber(int arg);
    }
    public class StaticNumber : INumbers
    {
        public int GetNumber(int arg)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public void DoStuff(INumbers num)
    {
        int i = 42;
        while ((i = num.GetNumber(i)) != 0)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
```

and then a simple

```
Action action = () => DoStuff(new StaticNumber());
```